# OpenCV, PyTorch, ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image

Tags: python, tile

I'm getting this error: ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image

During inference of a face recognition software that checks if you wear a covid mask or not.

This is the code

```
    transformations = Compose([
        ToPILImage(),
        Resize((100, 100)),
        ToTensor(),
    ])
    

[...]

    for frame in vreader(str(videopath)):
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        faces = faceDetector.detect(frame)
        for face in faces:
            xStart, yStart, width, height = face
            
            # clamp coordinates that are outside of the image
            xStart, yStart = max(xStart, 0), max(yStart, 0)
            
            # predict mask label on extracted face
            faceImg = frame[yStart:yStart+height, xStart:xStart+width]
            output = model(transformations(faceImg).unsqueeze(0).to(device))
            _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
            
            # draw face frame
            cv2.rectangle(frame,
                          (xStart, yStart),
                          (xStart + width, yStart + height),
                          (126, 65, 64),
                          thickness=2)
```

The main issue stems from  this snippet

```
output = model(transformations(faceImg).unsqueeze(0).to(device))
```

It might be the "detect" function in facedetector.py which is a separate element just for finding the faces in the picture:

```
def detect(self, image):
    """ detect faces in image
    """
    net = self.classifier
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    blob = blobFromImage(resize(image, (300, 300)), 1.0,
                         (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()
    faces = []
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
        if confidence < self.confidenceThreshold:
            continue
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([width, height, width, height])
        startX, startY, endX, endY = box.astype("int")
        faces.append(np.array([startX, startY, endX-startX, endY-startY]))
    return faces
```

I'm trying to run inference on a 1280x720p video. Not sure what's wrong. It begins the inference and from what I gather the model works but soon after it goes into that error...

What do you think?

This is the full stack of the error

```
File "video.py", line 66, in tagVideo
output = model(transformations(faceImg).unsqueeze(0).to(device))
```

File "C:\Users\User\Ana\anaconda3\envs\Venv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py", line 60, in **call**
img = t(img)
File "C:\Users\User\Ana\anaconda3\envs\Venv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py", line 179, in **call**
return F.to_pil_image(pic, self.mode)
File "C:\Users\User\Ana\anaconda3\envs\Venv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py", line 292, in to_pil_image
return Image.fromarray(npimg, mode=mode)
File "C:\Users\User\Ana\anaconda3\envs\Venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2793, in fromarray
return frombuffer(mode, size, obj, "raw", rawmode, 0, 1)
File "C:\Users\User\Ana\anaconda3\envs\Venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2733, in frombuffer
return frombytes(mode, size, data, decoder_name, args)
File "C:\Users\User\Ana\anaconda3\envs\Venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2679, in frombytes
im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
File "C:\Users\User\Ana\anaconda3\envs\Venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 796, in frombytes
d.setimage(self.im)

Comment: What is the shape of the tensor you are passing to the model? I suggest to check it. Also in your transformations why do you convert to PIL Image. That may be causing resizing problems.

Comment: @SarthakJain the shape of the tensor is (C x H x W) 

And I'm following a tutorial, fairly new to tensorflow. Do you have any advice on improving this? So thankful

Comment: I found this answer to seem pretty helpful workaround: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3044#issuecomment-375207867. Also, I think printing out detections and seeing how its values portrays on your PIL image could help with debugging in case you want to check if you are post processing output values incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused when you have invalid values for bboxes or array (if segmentation) and therefore cannot be used to index an image.

For example, a bbox like [10, 20, 30, 40] would work fine, but a bbox like
[10, -5, 30, 40] would not becuase of the negative value.

Also passing in bboxes like [] can cause this error.

Therefore, I recommend printing your bboxes to see if you are getting unexpected arrays like this.

Sarthak Jain

Comment: I'm getting a bbox of this size: [2644 1513  988  631]

Not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: Hi, is your bbox bigger than your image. Is any value in your bbox greater than the height or width of the image.